# Installing socket.io VCBuild.exe issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io, installation, npm

I wanted to try a cool node.js app I saw, for which I needed to install express and socket.io.
npm install express seemed to work fine, but when I tried npm install socket.io i got this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRvWW.jpg

Any tips on what actual file to install?
This seems pretty generic and for one i could probably only install visual studio 2013, not 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: Installing VS2013 should work fine.

Comment: that's what i thought, but also which of these should i download? Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web,  
Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows,  
Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop,  
Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2013

Comment: For desktop; that's the only one that has a C+ compiler.